# Using inputs as convolution filters in TensorFlow

Tags: tensorflow

I'm used to using learned filters in Tensorflow, applied on input data (or the output of a previous layer).

The input shape for `nn.conv2d` is `[h,w,in_channels,out_channels]`, and if my data is of shape `[?,n1,n2,1]` (first dimension is the minibatch size), then I would use as `shape` for `conv2d` `[h,w,1,m]` where `m` are the number of filters I want to learn.

But is it possible to use the input itself as a filter? that is, instead of learning the same filters for each slice of the minibatch, I would like to use a different filter to each slice - a filter derived directly from the input, that I do not learn.

For example, if my input data consists of two parts, both of them 2D and I have minibatch of 5, e.g. 
`D1 = [ [1,2] , [3,4] , [5,6] , [7,8] , [9,0] ]`

`D1 = [ [0,1] , [2,0] , [3,2] , [8,1] , [0,0] ]`

then I would like to perform convolution of `[1,2]` with `[0,1]`, of `[3,4]` with `[2,0]`, etc. (the dimensions are suitable in my case, this is just a demonstration).

Is it possible to do that using `nn.conv2d`? if not, will it be possible using `scan` or in any other way?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In your case, what you are calling 'convolution with filter derived from the input' is basically the element-wise multiplication followed by a reduce operation. For example, you can do the following :

```
sess = tf.InteractiveSession()
D1 = tf.constant([ [1,2] , [3,4] , [5,6] , [7,8] , [9,0] ])
D2 = tf.constant([ [0,1] , [2,0] , [3,2] , [8,1] , [0,0] ])

# Element-wise multiply D1 and D2, then reduce along dimension 1
result = tf.reduce_sum(D1 * D2, reduction_indices=[1])

print(result.eval())
# prints [ 2  6 27 64  0]
```

Comment: It was just an example - in my case I do have matrices there and I need to perform convolution.

Comment: Please specify the shapes of the two operands you want to convolve.

Comment: The sizes can change. The convolution is performed on a m x n matrix and an k x n filter (k<m).